# Automating jupyter notebook visualizations

Tags: python, dataframe, automation, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I have created a lot of visualization for a transaction data set of my company using jupyter notebook. Now I want to make that code reusable so that after my internship other people from my company will be able to generate those visualizations on next quarter data set. Also, they don't know python. Hence I need to create something that grabs data and throws the visualization without much hassle. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head i could think of many ideas here are some of them.

1. Using python interface (tkinter) that accepts the data from the user and show visualization.
2. Another solution could be you can create a web app using flask and accept the data from the user and visualize it.
3. If all of this is not possible you could easily create a script that accepts user data and then separate in 2 categories or dataframe for eg. object datatypes and numerical datatype and then plot using for loops.